# IBM Bluemix Login - Account Not Active

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am getting an error dialog "Account Not Active" when I try to login to IBM Bluemix with my IBM ID and then it automatically logs me out. Attached is the error dialog screen. Could anyone please help!

[IBM Bluemix - Account Not Active Error Dialog Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttLFe.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no ongoing login issues. It is probably a problem related to your account. I suggest you to open a support request using the following method:

- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Doing that you will engage the Bluemix Project Office Team that works on account and login issues to investigate your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Umberto Manganiello!